# What happens when an integration stream tries to rebase from or deliver to an integration stream it was seeded from?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

Scenario:
Integration stream `B` (of project `B`) was created by seeding from baseline `A_2.5` of integration `A` of project `A`).
After parallel development in both the streams the current recommended baseline of `A` is `A_3.2` and `B` is `B_1.5`.

Question:

- What happens if `B` tries to rebase from `A_3.2`?
- What happens if `B` tried to deliver to `A`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - `B` tries to rebase from `A_3.2`

That will trigger a merge between `B` LATEST content and `A_3.2` baseline content.

> - `B` tried to deliver to `A`

It is a merge from every new versions created on `B` since `A_2.5` (which is `B`'s baseline) and A LATEST content.
Obviously, is the deliver takes place after the aforementioned rebase, the delta to merge which be much smaller, and the deliver will be shorter and quicker.